# Have time to kill next week. Gonna do some location recordings. Any suggestions?

Tags: field-recording

Evening all!

I've got a week off next week and need to fill my time constructively by not watching any daytime tv lol Was thinking of going out and about to record some stuff and wondering if anyone had any specific requests? I live on the coast so stuff like waves/shores/gulls etc will be no probs. Was thinking of doing some stealth stuff too like public ambience sounds; malls, museums, gym, swimming pools, town centres, pub wallas etc. I'll be doing it with my Zoom H2 so if anyone wants anything specific let me know :)
Andy

edit: I live in Bournemouth, UK at present.

Comment: @Andy, did you manage to do any recording?

Comment: Hey Jay!
I did indeed. Not as much as I'd hoped but still enough of interest to someone hopefully ;) I'll get round to editing a bunch of them in the next week or so then get around to uploading them! I'll let you know when they're ready tho :)

Answer (score 1):

Hi guys,

I was in Brussels 2 days ago and now in Stockholm, Sweden. I've already recorded night traffic in Brussels and also at 5am exterior snow/water dripping. An interior airplane take off. In Stockholm since last night I've recorded traffic outside my hotel room. So, I'll be recording some more streets, room tone and since we're moving north I'm definetly gonna record some forests! Unfortunately all this with my Sony PCM D50 at 96Khz. But, hey, it's not bad either.

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly do you live?

Is there a small airport near where you live? Visit it and record some of those prop planes and such!

Maybe visit a zoo?

Take your recorder to a subway and hope there isn't many people around - I remember the Metro in L.A. sounding like a spaceship when it comes through.

Or visit a theme park like Six Flags or something and strap it to your chest (hopefully with good wind protection) and get the sounds of the people on the ride and the roller coasters etc.!

Possibilities are endless!

Comment: Hey Utopia! (what is your real name by the way?) lol I live in Bournemouth, UK at present. There is an airport but no real theme parks! Not so much looking for ideas as to where to record as such, but asking if anyone needs any particular sounds recorded. Think of it like a public service for the week! lol will be good to add to my library too so your suggestions will come in handy too ,)

Comment: Oooh I get it. Very nice of you! My real name is Ryan. I'll think about it and let you know =)

Comment: Hey @Andy maybe go to the dental practice section of Bournemouth and record some great servos and X-rays and things.

Answer (score 0):

A quick wiki search presented these opportunities, all of which I'd love to hear:

- The Bournemouth Pleasure Gardens;
- The graveyard at St. Peter's Church,
  Bournemouth, where Mary Shelley is
  buried;
- Traffic or other atmos from The
  Square;
- Interior or exterior atmos at
  Bournemouth University;
- Make a call to Parvalux (the UK's
  largest fractional horsepower motor)
  and see if you can get a tour?

If you're planning ahead, perhaps you can rent some better mics and a recorder for the air show coming up this August?

Comment: Hi Jay. Thanks for the reply! Having not too long graduated from Bournemouth Uni myself I'm sure I could sneak back around and get some recordings if you wanted ;) the air show is awesome. One year they had the Vulcan jet on display. That thing sounded HUGE. Would love to rent some decent gear for that this year! Will give the Parvalux peeps a shout and see what happens! Cheers for the tips :)

Comment: @Andy, rental fees for a weekend shouldn't run you too much, and you could potentially capture some incredible material at the air show. Re. the university and other locales, just walk around and see what you can get…students in the quad, cafeteria, lecture halls, rallys, etc. All are valuable and versatile.

Comment: @Andy Lewis, how did the recordings go? I'd love to hear anything you have.

Answer (score 0):

Try rooftop recording, plane recording from a distance, record everything through a tube/box/bottle, rustling in trees, make hydrophone recordings, do tons of contact mic recordings maybe while in a cardboard box or drinking glass, some walla

Answer (score 0):

The steam railway in Swanage runs on weekends. 
If you get to that area, go out in the open fields, far away from traffic, and record. You'll get a lot of hiss with a Zoom H2 but there's beauty in that too.

Answer (score 0):

Ideas off the top of my head.

Look up local festivals and events that you can get into for free and have the possibility of interesting sounds.

Head to old-school arcades, clock shops, and other more unusual shops.

Do you have any longer passways that have traffic and are accessible safely. Grab the difference sound of cars going in and out of the passway and reverb decay.

Answer (score 0):

I'd actually love some costal recordings.  Ports, docs, beaches, etc.  I'm inland so that kind of stuff isn't so easy for me to get to.

If you do manage to get that stuff shoot me a message and I'll trade some sounds for them.

thanks!

Comment: I'll no doubt be recording some of those sounds in the week so I'll let you know what I come up with and send you some stuff when I can ;)

Comment: @Rene, i have quite a few of those, and will have more soon, and i'm happy to share. shoot me an email if you want ->  filipe.chagas@gmail.com

that goes for other folks that have difficult access to that to

Answer (score 0):

I live at the seaside and have found it to be a great resource for unusual sounds that are hard to find elsewhere.

A particular favourite, although nothing special, is the sound of donkeys sauntering along with their bells (as in donkey rides on the beach).

Arcades would be ideal, however I've never had any success with permission, due to the copyright issues with the music and recordings played back on arcade machines. Unless you do it surreptitiously... But that would be a bit naughty!

Thinking of where you are, does the pier still stand? If you can get beneath it, the ambience, combined with the sound of the shore, could be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I think a good location, such as local shopping centers, cafes, markets, museum or school yard.
Lots of interesting sounds you can get.